# .each seemingly recursing into second dimension of 2D array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have just stumbled upon this way of iterating over 2-dimensional arrays in Ruby:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].each {|x| puts x}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

My question is simple: **why and how is this happening? Why is `Array#each` seemingly recursing into the second dimension?** Why is the output not as follows?

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]].each {|x| p x}`

Comment: "Why is Array#each seemingly recursing into the second dimension?" - `each` is not, `puts` is. `each` is irrelevant to your question. You can (and should) simplify your question by giving the code: `puts [1, 2]` instead of what you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the code to:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].each {|x| puts x.to_s}
```

Gives the expected output of:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

Turns out the magic is happening in [`IO#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts), not in `Array#each`. From the docs:

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

So `IO#puts` is recursive when given an array argument.

Comment: Yep. Object#inspect is often useful too:

`[[1, 2], [3, 4]].each {|x| puts x.inspect}`

would have revealed the same fact.